# Can no longer debug .vue files in vue3, how to resolve?

Tags: debugging, vuejs3

I created a vue3/vuetify3 project and from the start putting a "debugger" in any file of type .js or in the script section of any .vue file worked just fine.

But at some point it stopped working. When opening f.e Chrome and browsing a vue-component the debugger no longer stops on breakpoints that are inside a function in a .vue file. They do however still work on all other types of files, f.e main.js or any other .js file that I "import" to my vue pages.

I get the same behavior in chrome, edge and firefox. My colleague who's working on the same code got the same thing so at this point we cannot debug most of our functionality which is unfortunate.

What could I/we possible have done to make this happen? Or more importantly, how can we make debuggers work again?